# Xdebug issue with Eclipse PHP

Tags: eclipse, debugging, xampp, wamp, xdebug

I am currently trying to setup Xdebug on an XP computer with Eclipse PHP installed. I am using WAMP and I'll think I have done everything by the book (as intended by several tutorials online), but when I'll try to execute the Debugging and start the session, nothing happens, which also is notified by Eclipse. Another tab is opened with the GET-string appended in Firefox, but that's about it.

I have no Idea of what to do to make it work, but I'll guess that im not the first one having this issue, so asking here might not be a bad idea!

I am very grateful for any answers that could help me out in the right direction. Debugging is a brand new thing for me.

Thanks!

Here is also some info:

Eclipse says:

```
Launching: Waiting for Xdebug session
```

Here is how my php.ini looks:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0beta2-5.3-vc6.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=default
xdebug.remote_log="C:/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=9
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
```

And the URL:

```
http://localhost/debugtest/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=12658406113583
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stuff looks good but, how is your IDE setup?

What port is it listening on and what KEY is it sending?
Also, I always set a xdebug_break() breakpoint in code to get xdebug to catch and start talking to my IDE.

Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi! Thanks!
It's listening and sending on port 9000. Where can i find info about the KEY, since i am not using any proxy for Xdebug in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

After everything checked out correct (browser path, listening port, php -i, XDEBUG_SESSION_START=..., duct tape, etc.) and it still sat there waiting for Godot, rebooting fixed the problem.  Yay Windows.

Comment: That is probably because you have to restart apache after editing the php.ini file.